# MySQL Case statement in a View with Union All

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-view, union-all

I want to add a "Status" column to my view "v_file_details", which will have a value, depending on the data from "v_file_details.records_waiting_count" and "v_file_details.records_correct_count" columns. But I don't understand how can I use Case at the view?

```
create view v_file_details as
select 
fi.file_importer_id,
fi.file_name,
convert(time(0), fi.file_date) import_time,
fi.error_type,
((SELECT COUNT(*) From reservation Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('S', 'S1')) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From error_file_record Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id) +
(SELECT COUNT(*) From startup Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('T', '6'))) as records_correct_count,
((SELECT COUNT(*) From location Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status = 'Y') + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From reservation Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status = 'N') + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From startup Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('X', 'X1'))) as records_waiting_count,
case 'status' when records_waiting_count > 0 THEN 'Waiting' ELSE 'ACCEPTED', -- it is the problem, I don't know how to use CASE here
fi.new_file_name,

from file_importer fi
left join startup ts on fi.file_importer_id = ts.file_importer_id 
where ts.file_importer_id is not null

union all

select 
fi.file_importer_id,
fi.file_name,
convert(time(0), fi.file_date) import_time,
fi.error_type,
((SELECT COUNT(*) From reservation Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('S', 'S1')) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From error_file_record Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id) +
(SELECT COUNT(*) From startup Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('T', '6'))) as records_correct_count,
((SELECT COUNT(*) From location Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status = 'Y') + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From reservation Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status = 'N') + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From startup Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('X', 'X1'))) as records_waiting_count,
case 'status' when records_waiting_count > 0 THEN 'Waiting' ELSE 'ACCEPTED', --here the same
fi.new_file_name,

from file_importer fi
left join reservation res on fi.file_importer_id = res.file_importer_id 
where res.file_importer_id is not null

GO
```

Comment: You use `CASE` in a `SELECT` for a view the same way you'd do in a standalone `SELECT`, there's no difference. Try to explain what you want to achieve to get more detailed advise.

Comment: The `case` _expression_ needs an `end` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias in the `SELECT`, so you can't refer to `records_waiting_count`, you need to use the expression that it refers to. Also you already have a column called `status`, so you can't call the value of the `CASE` expression that (let's call it `waiting_status` instead). So your `CASE` expression should look like:

```
CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) From location Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status = 'Y') + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From reservation Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status = 'N') + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) From startup Where file_importer_id = fi.file_importer_id AND status in ('X', 'X1'))) > 0 THEN 'Waiting' ELSE 'Accepted' END AS waiting_status
```